# query soft deleted records in an Azure mobile app easy table

Tags: sqlite, azure, xamarin, soft-delete

I have a Azure mobile Easy Table Xamarin App that is a bunch of lists, reminders for myself. It works fine to add, update and delete. I want to be able to get a list of soft deleted items so I can undelete some to add them back into a list without retyping them. I cannot figure out how to do this. I see in  Google searches an IncludeDeleted attribute but it does not seem to apply to the IMobileServiceSyncTable table I am using. Here is the code, but it retrieves zero records. If I run it in LinqPad 5 I get all the soft deleted records.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ListData>> GetDeletedItemsAsync()
    {
        await InitializeClient();
        await SyncItems();

        try
        { 
            IEnumerable<ListData> items = await listdata
                .Where(listdata => listdata.Deleted == true )
                .ToEnumerableAsync();

            return new ObservableCollection<ListData>(items);
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Invalid sync operation: {0}", msioe.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Here is the Class:

```
public class ListData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "listname")]
    public string ListName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "itemdata")]
    public string ItemData { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "itemdetail")]
    public string ItemDetail { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deleted")]
    public Boolean Deleted { get; set; }
    // *** Enable Optimistic Concurrency *** //
    [Version]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to go directly to the server using an IMobileServiceTable object. It is pretty simple. You can then use the IncludeDeleted directive on the query. Case solved.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you could try to change your `SyncItems` method as follows:

```
private async Task SyncItems()
{
    var queryName = $"incsync:s:{typeof(ListData).Name}";
    var query = listDataTable.CreateQuery().IncludeDeleted();
    await listDataTable.PullAsync(queryName, query);
}
```

And you could use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces when invoking the above method, then you could check the response and find whether you could retrieve the deleted items.

Then you could leverage [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) or any other tool to check your local SQLite database and verify your table records to narrow this issue.

Comment: This gives and error that _deleted cannot be used as a parameter. I am starting to see that the issue is that what I want to do cannot be done with synced table, i.e.offline synced. This is not really a problem. I will have to use an IMobileServiceTable to get the deleted items directly from the server, then undelete the items I want undeleted and resync the synced table to view them in my App. I am a neophyte at this App programming and would appreciate conformation that I am on the right track, and some code sample for getting and updating records using the IMobileServiceTable<T> object..